# Touch panel via USB

Tags: usb, touchscreen

I have an old LG 19" (4:3) LCD display and I had an idea to connect it to an RPi which should not be a problem but then I had the idea of adding a touch-panel film over the LCD.

Now, I've Googled this for last few days and I cannot find any answers or anyone that has done this.

From what I've seen, there are touch panel films or layers that are pretty raw if you will, no connectors or boards with them and then you have touch panel layers that come with a board and a USB connector as a kit. An example would be: [eBay link](http://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/19-1-inch-USB-Panel-Kit-Set-Add-Touch-Screen-Function-/150622694170?pt=UK_Computing_Laptop_Screens_LCD_Panels&hash=item2311cfeb1a) <sup>*Editor note: if link rots - the title/search term was:* "19.1 inch USB Panel Kit Set - Add Touch Screen Function"</sup>.

Now the question would be of course if the example Touch Panel (link above) would work with RPi? I'm guessing that the problem would be in drivers for ARM, yes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It completely depends on what kind of controller they are using. However, since that panel looks like a single touch resistive panel it will most likely just be recognized as a mouse by your raspberry pi. The driver CD that comes with it most likely just has extra configuration options like hiding the mouse, allowing hold for right click etc...

The only way to be sure is to contact the seller. Ask him if the touch panel is recognized as an HID mouse without any driver install.

Comment: Hi, so basically I need a panel that is recognized as an HID mouse without any drivers for this to work? Sorry for stupid questions, fairly new to this stuff..

Comment: You are Correct. Also, it's not a stupid question at all. There are 2 ways to learn this stuff: ask questions, or blow money buying things that don't work. (You'll still end up blowing money, however, since you don't always know what questions to ask.)