# NOVA USB touch panel is working with raspberry

Tags: lcd

I need to use one touch panel for my LCD monitor 32 inch, so i found this kind of [NOVA USB touch panel](https://www.digikala.com/product/dkp-772092/%D9%81%D8%B1%DB%8C%D9%85-%D9%84%D9%85%D8%B3%DB%8C-%D9%85%D8%AF%D9%84-nova-%D9%85%D9%86%D8%A7%D8%B3%D8%A8-%D8%A8%D8%B1%D8%A7%DB%8C-%D9%86%D9%85%D8%A7%DB%8C%D8%B4%DA%AF%D8%B1-32-%D8%A7%DB%8C%D9%86%DA%86%DB%8C#/tab-params) :

[image]
[image]

in the description it said it is working with Linux OS and working without needing to any software!!!.

AT [this question](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/8758/touch-panel-via-usb) said:

> completely depends on what kind of controller they are using.
>   However, since that panel looks like a single touch resistive panel it
>   will most likely just be recognized as a mouse by your raspberry pi.
>   The driver CD that comes with it most likely just has extra
>   configuration options like hiding the mouse, allowing hold for right
>   click etc...
>
> The only way to be sure is to contact the seller. Ask him if the touch
>   panel is recognized as an HID mouse without any driver install.

Or [via here](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/28/how-can-i-determine-if-a-given-touchscreen-is-compatible) it said :

> As of 2018, the easiest way to check if any screen works with
>   Raspberry Pi is looking for references to device tree

But i don't find any datasheet for this touch panel via internet and no **device tree** for it.

As you can see there is no driver with is, So is this touch panel working with my raspberry, and which kind of driver i need to by for it?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The panel looks like an IR frame.

There is no touch surface.

There is a matrix of IR beams that detect a touch when something interrupts the beam.

It is probably seen as an ordinary mouse, so it requires no driver.

Such a device usually does not support multi-touch.

Comment: So is this device works with raspberry?I don't find any datasheet for it, base of what i could write the source code for analysing its output data's in raspberry?

Comment: i know nothing about the device ... i was only making an observation ... the possibility is strong that it is seen as a mouse ... if it is seen as a mouse, then it should work .... ask the seller to confirm its operation